# virtual directory asp.net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to create a new directory in my local IIS, and what I want is to able to run my website as www.localsitename.com/mywebsite where the mywebsite is an application in IIS configured to my application location(C:\mydocument\folder....)

usually in VS 2010 I used to edit the project file and add entry in the  in the IISUrl but when I try the same thing in VS 2012, I get an error can't create virtual directory, and they suggest that it must use the localhost.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Regards

Comment: Can you give the exact error that is shown in Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi this is the error creation of the virtual directory www.localsitename.com/mywebsite failed with error: cannot create the website [link] (www.localsitename.com/mywebsite) you must specify localhost for the servername and when I specify localhost I can run it as http://localhost:8080 but this isn't what I want as I need to have a feel and touch of how it will be once live Thanks

Comment: Once live, you'd just have `localhost` replaced with whatever server your app is hosted on. The virtual paths would be the same though. Perhaps you're looking to [rename your localhost](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/700646)?

Comment: thanks that is what I was missing just for info on anyone looking to do this, you need to enter www.localsitename.com in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts hope this help one person or another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your localhost name as described [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/700646).